# How to copy all image in excel one by one in picturebox?

Tags: excel, vb6, vba

How can I copy images from excel into picturebox? I have this code but it has an error saying "Activex cant create object" and it happens when i install or create an exe for a user.

```
Private Sub cmdsave_Click()

    If Text1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Unable to segregate picture. No file selected."
    Else

        Dim appExcel As Object



        Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        appExcel.Visible = False
        Dim xlsBook  As New excel.Workbook
        Dim xlsSheet As New excel.Worksheet

        Dim rowlocation As Integer
        Dim columnlocation As Integer
        Dim celladdress As String



        Set xlsBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(Text1.Text)
        Set xlsSheet = xlsBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
     Dim x As excel.Shapes



        For Each x In xlsSheet.Shapes
            x.Copy
            Picture1.Picture = Clipboard.GetData(vbCFBitmap)
            Text2.Text = x.Name
            rowlocation = x.TopLeftCell.Row
            columnlocation = x.TopLeftCell.Column
            celladdress = xlsSheet.Cells(x.BottomRightCell.Row + 1, x.TopLeftCell.Column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
            MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(celladdress)
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

TYSM for future help

Comment: Yes sir your 100% right they are using Openoffice :( Its working fine on my PC since i have excel but then the user dont use that what other ways i can do? pls help me :(

Comment: I am trying to display excel using ado but how can i get all of the image one by one? and I think its not possible

Comment: I hope theres away to run excel in vb6 without exel installed

Comment: No you can't automate Excel from VB6 without Excel installed.  And you can't pull out images using ADO...

Comment: I have no idea. You could look for a library which can be used from VB6 to read Excel files, but that's off-topic here.